# Move the "Chat" feature link to better real estate

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, chat, user-interface

**Currently, the Chat feature link is hidden at the bottom of the page, leaving only experienced GIS users to find it.**

[image: Chat link on bottom of page]

The result is two fold:

1. People (mostly new users) are posting *chat-worthy* discussion questions on the main Q&A site, which would be more appropriate on the chat site. They get their "hand slapped" for posting discussion questions, and I doubt that many of them return to the site.
2. People are missing out on the conversations in the chat arena, and there is typically little traffic on the page.

[image]
If we were able to add the Chat feature as a top-billed tab, we might be able to:

1. Reduce the number of *chat-worthy* questions on the main site
2. Increase the amount of traffic on the chat site.

My proposed layout is below:

[image: Chat feature on top]

**Thoughts?**

Answer (score 4):

To achieve a change such as this the place to ask would be Meta Stack Exchange because it is not something that can be customized on a per-site basis.

That question has already been asked there as:

[Include both the chat and blog links permanently in the header](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/103077/215590)

What I think prevents the Chat button being made more prominent is that chat is designed for things that don't fit on Main. Consequently, it is likely that the turn off to new users would be far higher if they thought the preponderance of chatter and relative scarcity of answers was representative of Stack Exchange.

I think it is better to redirect the occasional (even relatively frequent) poor question to chat rather than to try and have new users arrive via chat.

Answer (score 3):

If you click on the **StackExchange logo** with the arrow pointing down you get to the chat much quicker.

[image]

Comment: That is certainly a quick method of accessing chat, but I would argue that it is still fairly hidden (within a dropdown menu). For our one-off users (and even some experienced users--see edit), I would still argue benefit in having the "Chat" button next to the "Ask Question" button.

Comment: We [GIS SE Moderators] don't have access to change this on GIS.SE you would need to go to it's creators https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky